# What is the difference between Session.Abandon() and Session.Clear() in ASP.Net?

Tags: asp.net, session, session-state

What is the difference between `Session.Abandon()` and `Session.Clear()` in ASP.Net?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1470445/what-is-the-difference-between-session-abandon-and-session-clear (Yeah, I know this is over five years late. I just noticed a forum post elsewhere that posted to both of these. :) )

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`Session.Abandon()` will end the current session. `Session_End` will be fired and the next request will fire the `Session_Start` event.

`Session.Clear` will just clear the session data and the the session will remain alive.

Session ID will remain the same in both cases, as long as the browser is not closed.

**In a nutshell:**

`Session.Abandon();` cancels the current `Session`.

`Session.Clear();` clears all values from `Session` state.

Answer (score 1):

```
Session.Abandon()
```

will destroy/kill the entire session.

```
Session.Clear()
```

removes/clears the session data (i.e. the keys and values from the current session) but the session will be alive.

Compare to Session.Abandon() method, Session.Clear() doesn't create the new session, it just make all variables in the session to NULL.

Session ID will remain same in both the cases, as long as the browser is not closed.

Answer (score 0):

Some things to note here from my experience:

`Session.Abandon()` does not invalidate the current session. Old requests execute fine if you replay them.

But, after you call it, setting the contents of the abandoned session dictionary have no permanent effect. The next request gets a fresh new session dictionary (even if you use the same session ID by replaying a previous request) and none of your previous changes to it (after having called the method) are there.

So, it seems that `Session.Abandon()` totally stops the persistence of the entire session, while `Session.Clear()` only removes its data.

And, also, if you need to secure your application from replay attacks, you should add some logic that validates sessions and not depend on any of these built-in methods. Those seem to be meant for only managing the persistence of the session data, not for securing your application.