# How do you unauthenticate User.Identity

Tags: asp.net, authentication, identity

Within an ASP.Net application I am working on, the process is as follows.

1. The user logs in.
2. If this is the first time the user has logged into the system ever, it authenticates the user then redirects to update the password
3. If the user updates the password, they continue on without problems
4. However, if the user cancels out of updating their password the user is redirected back to the login page.

Now I want to be able to unauthenticate the user at this point #4 if they deicde not to update their password. How would I go about doing that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this question in SO. It contains the answer to your question and a lot more useful information:

[What is the difference between Session.Abandon() and Session.Clear() in ASP.Net?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3021688/what-is-the-difference-between-session-abandon-and-session-clear-in-asp-net)

**Edit:** and just to be more specific, [Abandon](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.sessionstate.httpsessionstate.abandon.aspx) is what you're looking for.