# Why can't destroy just one session

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, performance, session

Q:

I know that to destroy all sessions , i can use:

```
Session.Abandon()
```

According to my [question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6640350/c-clear-session)

but why there is n't any equivalent method to destroy only one session. and i am supposed to use

```
Session.Remove("varName")
```

instead of.

Comment: What do you mean by *destroy only one session* ?

Comment: I mean the effect of `Session.Abandon()` but only on one session instead of all my sessions .look to my question here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6640350/c-clear-session

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First of all, you are talking about session variables, not sessions. Each user has one session and one `Session` object that you can store several variables in.

You use the `Session.Abandon` to abandon the session once the current request completes, which will remove the `Session` object.

You use the `Session.Remove` method to remove one variable from the `Session` object.

Comment: Thanks a lot.I'm sorry , I miss this concept .really thank u so much.

Answer (score 1):

`Session.Clear()` will remove all items from the session-state collection while `Session.Remove(<item name>)` will remove only the one item from the collection and leave the remainder intact.  `Session.Abandon()` will destroy the whole session and start a new session.

Answer (score 1):

You are mistaken between Session and Session Variables. A User viewing your site is assigned only 1 session and in this 1 session object, you can store many session variables.

`Session.Abandon` will remove the current session of the connected user.

`Session.Remove` will remove specific session variables as mentioned by you.

`Session.Clear` will remove all the session variables of the session but will not remove the session.

---

Refer to the following links for the Session and its usage:

[CodeProject: Exploring Session in ASP.NET](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/ExploringSession.aspx)

[ASP.NET Session State](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972429.aspx)

[ASP.NET Session state overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178581.aspx)