# session in IIS always empty (between pages)

Tags: asp.net, iis

I have floder in wwwroot that contain all the pages for a website.

the problem is that session and cookies are not save between the pages, although that the session is recognized, but always empty!

What do I have to do in order to enable session and cookies between the pages?

I tried adding this line to web.config

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms   cookieless="AutoDetect" domain="" timeout="10" protection="All" />
</authentication>
```

And I turn the folder to an Application throw the IIS manager tools.

but nothing :(

the IIS version is 7

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked that session state is enabled in IIS7?

- http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc725624%28WS.10%29.aspx

You also need to ensure that you have the session state config setting setup in your web.config in your application.

Here's an example of mine

```
<sessionState mode="InProc" stateConnectionString="tcpip=127.0.0.1:42424" sqlConnectionString="data source=127.0.0.1;Trusted_Connection=yes" cookieless="false" timeout="20" />
```

You should check out

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178586.aspx

**Edit**: updated the above link, the previous one was defunct.

Comment: Don't accept until you know it's working.  It could be any of either IIS7 or the sessionstate string in your web.config. ^_^

Comment: unfortunately Those guides are not working for me ,the session state was already "in proc",additionally I added the <sessionState mode="InProc"... to my web config but still the session is restart in every refresh of the page(or when direct between the pages).the strange thing is, that the browser is recognize the session(not null or nothing) but it just empty

Comment: You can check several things, 1 check to see if your browser is accepting cookies, I think by default the server keeps session state by sending cookies.  Also check to see that you are not clearing the session state on page load.  - [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6640350/c-clear-session](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6640350/c-clear-session)