# How to use Session and Authentication timeouts in ASP.NET MVC 4

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, c#-4.0, authentication

I have a `ShoppingCart` to store items for `User`. Now I want when each time `User` log-out, it will be clear a `ShoppingCart` of that `User`! What's function I will use in this situation? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6640350/c-sharp-clear-session) post.

Alternately, depending on the situation, you can clear out the session on start/login of your application. I use this approach as well.