# how to log out of session MVC Razor visual studio

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I'm trying to logout from a session in MVC Razor heres what I have in my MainController at the moment:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Login(Users user)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        if (ValidateUser(user.Email, user.Password))
        {

            FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(user.Email, false);
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Members");
        }
        else
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError("", "");
        }
    }
    return View();
}

private bool ValidateUser(string Email, string Password)
{

    bool isValid = false;

    using (var db = new ShareRideDBEntities())
    {
        var User = db.tblProfiles.FirstOrDefault(u => u.PROF_Email == Email);
        var ut = db.tblProfilesTypes.FirstOrDefault(t => t.TPE_ID == User.PROF_UserType);

        if (User != null)
        {
            if (User.PROF_Password == Password)
            {
                Session["UserID"] = User.PROF_UserID;
                Session["Name"] = User.PROF_FirstName;
                Session["Email"] = User.PROF_Email;
                Session["FullName"] = User.PROF_FirstName + " " + User.PROF_LastName;

                isValid = true;
            }
        }

    }

    return isValid;
}
```

With this I can login the user and reditect it to his UserCP or user control panel.

I have it so that if the user is not logged in, they will not be able to access the members area with this code in my MembersController:

```
public ActionResult UserCP()
{
    if (Session["UserID"] == null)
    {
        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Main");
    }
    else
    {
        return View();
    }

}

public ActionResult LogOut()
{
    FormsAuthentication.SignOut();
    return RedirectToAction("index", "main");
}
```

It will redirect the user back to the main index page if he/she is not logged in yet, but when I test the logout button it redirects me normally but I am still able to go back to the user control panel which is what I don't want to it happen.

Of course I have added

```
using System.Web.Security;
```

to use the FormAuthentication.SignOut();

Thanks in advance if anyone can explain this.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

After `FormsAuthentication.SignOut();` You need to call [`Session.Abandon()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.sessionstate.httpsessionstate.abandon(v=vs.110).aspx) that will clear current session and recreate new session on the next request

```
public ActionResult LogOut()
{
    FormsAuthentication.SignOut();
    Session.Abandon(); // it will clear the session at the end of request
    return RedirectToAction("index", "main");
}
```

Comment: The Session.End() gives a compile error but if you try Session.Clear(); it does the job. Are they the same thing?

Comment: Yeah, i missed with correct method. I updated answer. The correct is `Session.Abandon()`. The difference between them is that `Clear` will remove all items from session after the call. But `Abandon` will destroy session itself at the end of current request and will call Session_End event. They are similar things. You can check differences here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6640350/c-sharp-clear-session

Answer (score 2):

`Session.Clear` and `Session.RemoveAll` are identical; the latter just calls the former. They immediately remove all items stored in the session, but the session itself survives. `Session_OnEnd` does not fire.

`Session.Abandon` doesn't actually clear the values immediately, it just marks the session to be abandoned at the end of the current request. You can continue to read the values for the rest of the request. If you write to the session later in the request, the new value will be quietly discarded at the end of the request with no warning. `Session_OnEnd` fires at the end of the request, not when Abandon is called. you can use all like this.

```
public ActionResult LogOut()
{
    FormsAuthentication.SignOut();
    Session.Clear();
    Session.RemoveAll();
    Session.Abandon(); 
    return RedirectToAction("index", "main");
}
```