# Does HttpContext.Current.Session gets destroyed when AuthenticationManager.SignOut(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have `HttpContext.Current.Session["CurrentUser"] = user;` somewhere in my code and in the logout I have this

```
public ActionResult LogOff()
{
           AuthenticationManager.SignOut(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
}
```

I just want to make sure that `HttpContext.Current.Session` is also destoyed when I logoff. If not then how do it destroy it?

Comment: [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178581.aspx) suggest to call session `Abandon()` after logout. Refer the third note in the link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the server will hold on to `Session` data for 20 minutes by default, unless you do something explicit.

But you can clear particular Session variables on logout or abandon the session.

See here for more info: [What is the difference between Session.Abandon() and Session.Clear()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1470445/what-is-the-difference-between-session-abandon-and-session-clear)